# Wrapping C# primitives in struct performance implications

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing some code on geometry processing, delaunay triangulation to be more specific, and I need it to be fast, so I use simple arrays of primitive as data structure to represent my triangulation information, here is a sample of it

```
        private readonly float2[] points;
        private readonly int[] pointsHalfEdgeStartCount;
        private readonly int[] pointsIncomingHalfEdgeIndexes;
```

So let's say I want to iterate fast through all the incoming half-edge of the point of index p, I just do this using the precomputed arrays:

```
int count = pointsHalfEdgeStartCount[p * 2 + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var e = pointsIncomingHalfEdgeIndexes[pointsHalfEdgeStartCount[p * 2] + i]
}

// pointsHalfEdgeStartCount[p * 2] is the start index
```

And this is fast enought, but does not feel safe or very clear. So I had the idea of wrapping my index into struct to make it clearer while retaining the performance, somthing like that:

```
public readonly struct Point
{
    public readonly int index;
    public readonly DelaunayTriangulation delaunay

    public Point(int index, DelaunayTriangulation delaunay)
    {
        this.index = index; 
        this.delaunay = delaunay;
    }

            
    public int GetIncomingHalfEdgeCount() => delaunay.pointsEdgeStartCount[index * 2 + 1];
    public HalfEdge GetIncomingHalfEdge(int i)
    {
        return new HalfEdge(
            delaunay,
            delaunay.pointsIncomingHalfEdgeIndexes[delaunay.pointsEdgeStartCount[index * 2] + i]
        );
    }

    //... other methods
}
```

Then I can just do so:

```
int count = p.GetIncomingHalfEdgeCount();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var e = p.GetIncomingHalfEdge(i);
}
```

However it was kind of killing my performance, being a lot slower (around 10 times) on a benchmark I did, iterating over all the points and iterating over all their incoming half-edge. I guess because storing a reference to the delaunay triangulaiton in each point struct was an obvious waste and slowed down all the operations involving points, having twice the amount of data to move.

I could make the DelaunayTriangulation a static class but it was not practical for other reasons, so I did that:

```
public readonly struct Point
{
    public readonly int index;
    
    public Point(int index) => this.index = index;

            
    public int GetIncomingHalfEdgeCount(DelaunayTriangulation delaunay) => delaunay.pointsEdgeStartCount[index * 2 + 1];
    public HalfEdge GetIncomingHalfEdge(DelaunayTriangulation delaunay, int i)
    {
        return new HalfEdge(
            delaunay.pointsIncomingHalfEdgeIndexes[delaunay.pointsEdgeStartCount[index * 2] + i]
        );
    }

    //... other methods
}
```

I can just do so:

```
int count = p.GetIncomingHalfEdgeCount(delaunay);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var e = p.GetIncomingHalfEdge(delaunay, i);
}
```

It was quite a lot faster, but still 2.5 times slower than the first method using simple int. I wondered if it could be because I was getting int in the first method while I got HalfEdge struct in the other methods (A struct similar to the Point struct, contains only an index as data and a couple of methods), and difference between plain int and the faster struct vanished when I used the e int to instantiate a new HalfEdge struct. Though I am not sure why is that so costly.Weirder still, I explored for clarity sake the option of wrinting the method inside the Delaunay class instead of the Point struct:

```
// In the DelaunayTriangulation class:

public int GetPointIncomingHalfEdgeCount(Point p) => pointsEdgeStartCount[p.index * 2 + 1];
public HalfEdge GetPointIncomingHalfEdge(Point p, int i)
{
    return new HalfEdge(
        pointsIncomingHalfEdgeIndexes[pointsEdgeStartCount[p.index * 2] + i]
        );
}
```

And I used it like this:

```
int count = delaunay.GetPointIncomingHalfEdgeCount(p);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var e = delaunay.GetPointIncomingHalfEdge(p, i);
}
```

And it was 3 times slower than the previous method! I have no idea why.

I tried to use disassembly to see what machine code was generated but I failed to do so (I am working with Unity3D). Am I condemned to rely on plain int in arrays and sane variable naming and to renounce on trying to have some compile-time type checking (is this int really a point index ?)

I am not even bringing up other questions such as, why it is even slower when I try to use IEnumerable types with yields like so:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetPointIncomingHalfEdges(Point p)
{
    int start = pointsEdgeStartCount[p.index * 2]; // this should be a slight optimization right ?
    int count = pointsEdgeStartCount[p.index * 2 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield pointsIncomingHalfEdgeIndexes[start + i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to open the [`Profiler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) enable [`Deep profile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html#deep-profiling) run your code with lots of entries and see where exactly performance is eaten ;) Note that especially also all the dynamic calculations of the indices might be expensive in your case

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help me much, I do not get more information about what eats my time than the profiling I did by calling the methods a great number of time with a stopwatch. Also I don't know what you mean by dynamic calculations of indices.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a compiler directive for aggressive inlining and it seems to make up for the discrepencies in time! For some reason the compiler fails to inline correctly for:

```
var e = delaunay.GetPointIncomingHalfEdge(p, i);
```

While it managed to do so with

```
var e = p.GetIncomingHalfEdge(delaunay, i);
```

Why ? I do not know. However It would be far easier if I was able to see how the code is compiled and I could not find how to do that. I will search that, maybe open another question and if I find a better explaination I will come back!